# Converting a Dictionary from one type to another

Tags: .net, generics, dictionary, types

How can I convert a `Dictionary(Of TypeA, TypeB)` to a `Dictionary(Of TypeC, TypeD)`? There is an implicit cast when converting (let's say the second dictionary is `String, String`), so this process should be automatic, right? I just can't figure out an elegant way to do this.

The language is VB.NET, but I can read and convert C# if you're more comfortable with that.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you are trying to do ?  As far as I understand you want your dictionary to support both TypeA/TypeC and TypeB/TypeD ?  Are TypeC and TypeD derived versions of TypeA and TypeB respectively?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would use Linq for cases like this. There's a `ToDictionary()` method that converts any generic IEnumerable (and a `Dictionary<TA,TB>` is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TA,TB>>`) to a Dictionary by taking two projections of the Enumerable element to produce a key and value for the dictionary. It makes these kinds of conversions very simple:

```
Dictionary<TypeA, TypeB> myDictionary = new Dictionary<TypeA, TypeB>
                                            { 
                                               /*initialization here*/ 
                                            };
Dictionary<TypeC, TypeD> myChangedDictionary = 
    myDictionary.ToDictionary(x=>x.Key.AsTypeC(), x=>x.Value.AsTypeD())
```

AsTypeC() and AsTypeD() are placeholders for whatever conversion is necessary to go from A/B to C/D. You suggested the second Dictionary was a `Dictionary<string,string>`; in that case you'd simply ToString() both of them (if you've overridden that method) or use the Key/Value in some String.Format operation.

Comment: ToDictionary was the one-line solution that I ended up using, since the resulting dictionary was just <String, String>.

Comment: Thanks!. It saves my one hour.

Answer (score 4):

```
 public static class DictionaryExtensions {
     public static Dictionary<TProjectedKey, TProjectedValue> ConvertDictionary<
         TKey,
         TValue,
         TProjectedKey, 
         TProjectedValue
     >(
         this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
         Func<TKey, TProjectedKey> keyProjection,
         Func<TValue, TProjectedValue> valueProjection
     ) {
         Contract.Requires(dictionary != null);
         Contract.Requires(keyProjection != null);
         Contract.Requires(valueProjection != null);
         Contract.Requires(dictionary.Select(kvp => keyProjection(kvp.Key))
                                     .AllValuesAreUnique()
                          );
         return dictionary.ToDictionary(
             kvp => keyProjection(kvp.Key),
             kvp => valueProjection(kvp.Value)
         );
     }
 }
```

The last `Contract.Requires` is saying that `keyProjection` is required to be one-to-one on `dictionary.Keys`. The method `IEnumerable<TSource>.AllValuesAreUnique` is an extension method that I'm sure you can figure out how to write.

Then, you can say:

```
Dictionary<Foo, Bar> dictionary = // some dictionary;
var projection = dictionary.ConvertDictionary(
    foo => foo.ToString(),
    bar => bar.ToString()
);
```

> so this process should be automatic, right?

I see no reason why this should be automatic. If the types are different, their hash codes are likely different, etc. The "converted" dictionary effectively needs to be built from scratch.

Comment: What we're doing is more `Convert` than `Project`, wouldn't you say?

Comment: @AakashM: Sure, I changed the name. Thanks.

Comment: You understand that this extension method is redundant; the Linq library already has a ToDictionary() method for IEnumerables (and a Dictionary is an IEnumerable) that works identically.