# Convert Dictionary(Of String, Object) to Dictionary(Of String, String)

Tags: vb.net

When I try to pass a `Dictionary(Of String, Object)` to a function parameter that wants a `Dictionary(Of String, String)` I get the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.String,System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.String,System.String]'.

All of the `Object` values in the dictionary are strings but the dictionary was declared as `String/Object`. I would have thought that the system would be able to convert this but since it isn't I need to do it myself.

I looked at the `.ToDictionary()` prototype method but all of the examples show a list being converted to a dictionary.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507804/converting-a-dictionary-from-one-type-to-another) which has an accepted answer for what I want but it's written in C# and I can't figure out the conversion to VB.Net.

**Edit 1**

Offending code. Obviously boiled down or else I would just simply declare `dict1` as `string/string` in my actual code.

```vb
Dim dict1 As New Dictionary(Of String, Object) From {{"key1","value1"}}

SomeFunctionThatExpectsParamToBeDictOfStringString(dict1)
```

**Edit 2**

I tried:

```vb
SomeFunctionThatExpectsParamToBeDictOfStringString(dict1.ToDictionary(Function(k) k.Key, Function(v) v.Value.ToString()))
```

but got:

> System.MissingMemberException: Public member 'ToDictionary' on type 'Dictionary(Of String,Object)' not found.

Comment: Please post the offending code.

Comment: If you really know every item is a string, the best solution here is to change the declaration of the dictionary.

Comment: Despite the example given, It's not as simple as that.

Comment: Regardless of the fact that *you* know all of the `Object`s are really `String`s, the type system doesn't know that (if it did, it would be a `Dictionary(Of String, String)` rather than a `Dictionary(Of String, Object)`).  And while it might make sense to treat a dictionary from string to string as a dictionary from string to object, it really doesn't make sense to go in the other direction, because the dictionary can legally contain things that aren't strings.

Comment: The dictionary is generated inside of, and returned from a method. Sometimes this dictionary does need to be a string/object because the objects are a mix of strings, integers, and decimals.  In other cases, it is a string/object where the objects are all strings.  Regardless, I should be able to convert the dict of string/object to string/string since all of the potential objects can easily be converted to a string value.  It just so happens that I only need to convert this dict of string/object when all the objects are strings but again, it shouldn't matter if that was not the case either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be the VB.NET version of the [C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507804/converting-a-dictionary-from-one-type-to-another) you have linked

```
Dim dic1 As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = New Dictionary(Of String, Object) 
dic1.Add("A", "B")

Dim dic2 As Dictionary(Of String, String) = dic1.ToDictionary(Function(k) k.Key, 
                                                              Function(v) v.Value.ToString())
```

Comment: Please see Edit2

Comment: That's seems to be a missing Imports System.Linq

Comment: Same error.  I don't think its related but the dictionary I am trying to convert is the result of a Union of two other dictionaries:  dict1.Union(dict2).ToDictionary(Function(d) d.Key, Function(d) d.Value)

Comment: I have tried to declare another Dictionary(Of String, Object) and initialized it with some values. Then using dict1.Union with this third dictionary but I am not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `.ToDictionary` doesn't change `dic1`. It produces a new dictionary. Trying to pass dic1 will not have desired result. Try assigning to a new variable of the proper type before passing to your function

Comment: @Mary yes, that's what I am doing above (however, even the last attempt from the OP should be working). The weird thing is that this seems to be a runtime exception, not a compiler error. If the ToDictionary method doesn't exist they should not be able to compile the program. Something happens dynamically then?

Comment: @Steve, I agree this should be working.  I am accepting your answer.  As far as something happening dynamically, the dictionary is being built and returned from a function.  When debugging, the returned dictionary looks like this:  System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]]} System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of String, Object)